# JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, backend

So I am trying to learn how to create a JSON database with PHP using BIZ.nf hosting. I created the PHP files that post data on the JSON file using insomnia to handle the GET and POST commands. Whenever I google the domain link it shows the proper JSON format and data, but whenever I try to parse it I get the ***"JSON could not be serialized because of error:
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."***

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
class Listings {

struct listingData {
    var restaurantLogo = " "
    var name = " "
    var offer = " "
}

var listingsArray: [listingData] = []
let listingURL = "http:///www.fredidbs-2018.co.nf/api/listings.json"

func getListings(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(listingURL).responseJSON {response in
        switch response.result {
    case .success(let value) :
        let json = JSON(value)
        let numberOfListings = json.count
        //print(json)
        print(numberOfListings)
        for index in 0...numberOfListings  {
            let name = json[index]["Name"].stringValue
            let restaurantLogo = json[index]["Logo"].stringValue
            let offer =  json[index]["Offer"].stringValue
            self.listingsArray.append(listingData(restaurantLogo: restaurantLogo, name: name, offer: offer))
            print(">>>> DATE CHECK, \(restaurantLogo) \(name) \(offer) \(numberOfListings)")
        }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("****** ERROR: failed to get data \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        completed()
    }
}}
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to create the PHP backend for an iOS app to parse.

Comment: There are 3 slashes (`/`) after `http:` in that URL in your code, which could lead to some potentially odd results. What happens if you remove one of the slashes (`/`)?

Comment: Output the raw response and make sure you are receiving what you expect to receive in your APP. Check it against any number of the free online validators.

Comment: It could be that there is no `Content-Type: application/json` header in the HTTP response from http:///www.fredidbs-2018.co.nf/api/listings.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire Post Request Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277005/alamofire-post-request-issues)